# Why do I get this error 'jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'search_value' is undefined'? And I can't see the data in the data table

Tags: python, html, css, flask

This is main html code that's name is 'data.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Dashboard - SB Admin</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="static/css/styles_login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/animate.css">
        <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/icomoon.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.css">
        <!-- Superfish -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/superfish.css">
        <!-- Magnific Popup -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/magnific-popup.css">
        <!-- Date Picker -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
        <!-- CS Select -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/cs-select.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/cs-skin-border.css">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">

        <!-- Modernizr JS -->
        <script src="static/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">

        <div id="fh5co-wrapper">
        <div id="fh5co-page">

        <header id="fh5co-header-section" class="sticky-banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-header">
                    <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle dark"><i></i></a>
                    <h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="/index2"></i>Bean</a></h1>
                    <!-- START #fh5co-menu-wrap -->
                    <nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="/index2">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="layoutSidenav">
            <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/data">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                                Dashboard
                            </a>
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Interface</div>
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseLayouts" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
                                Layouts
                                <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="collapseLayouts" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                                <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layout-static.html">Static Navigation</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layout-sidenav-light.html">Light Sidenav</a>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsePages" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></div>
                                Pages
                                <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="collapsePages" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                                <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav accordion" id="sidenavAccordionPages">
                                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseAuth" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseAuth">
                                        Authentication
                                        <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseAuth" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                                        <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseError" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseError">
                                        Error
                                        <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseError" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                                        <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="401.html">401 Page</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="500.html">500 Page</a>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Addons</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i></div>
                                Charts
                            </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Tables
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                        <div class="small">Logged in as:</div>
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <h1 class="mt-4">Dashboard
                                                    <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="searchInput" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" /> 
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </h1>
                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                // 검색 버튼이 클릭되었을 때
                                $('#btnNavbarSearch').click(function () {
                                    // 사용자의 검색어 가져오기
                                    var searchValue = $('#searchInput').val();
                                    
                                    // 검색어가 '시청', '종각', 또는 '서울'인지 확인
                                    if (searchValue === '시청') {
                                        // 시청역에 해당하는 경로로 리디렉션
                                        window.location.href = '/si_station_daily_data';
                                    } else if (searchValue === '종각') {
                                        // 종각역에 해당하는 경로로 리디렉션
                                        window.location.href = '/jong_station_daily_data';
                                    } else if (searchValue === '서울') {
                                        // 서울역에 해당하는 경로로 리디렉션
                                        window.location.href = '/se_station_daily_data';
                                    }
                                });

                                // 기본 그래프 아이콘 설정
                                var defaultGraphIcons = '<i class="fas fa-chart-area me-1"></i><i class="fas fa-chart-bar me-1"></i>';
                                
                                // 기본 그래프 아이콘 표시
                                $('#graphIcons').html(defaultGraphIcons);
                                
                                // 검색어에 따라 그래프 아이콘 업데이트
                                $('#searchInput').on('input', function () {
                                    var searchValue = $(this).val();
                                    var graphIcons = defaultGraphIcons;
                                    
                                    if (searchValue === '시청') {
                                        graphIcons = '<i class="fas fa-chart-area me-1"></i><i class="fas fa-chart-bar me-1"></i>';
                                    } else if (searchValue === '종각' || searchValue === '서울') {
                                        graphIcons = '<i class="fas fa-chart-bar me-1"></i>';
                                    }
                                    
                                    $('#graphIcons').html(graphIcons);
                                });
                            });
                        </script>

                        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard</li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Primary Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-warning text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Warning Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-success text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Success Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-danger text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Danger Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-area me-1"></i>
                                        {{ search_value }}의 일별 승차총승객수
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; overflow: auto;">
                                        {% if graph_image %}
                                            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=graph_image) }}" alt="{{ search_value }}의 일별 승차총승객수">
                                        {% else %}
                                            <p>그래프 이미지를 찾을 수 없습니다.</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            

                            <!-- Load Chart.js library -->
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
                            
                            <!-- Load and execute chart-area-demo.js -->
                            <div class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar me-1"></i>
                                        {{ search_value }}의 요일별 승차총승객수
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; overflow: auto;">
                                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=search_value.lower() + '_station_weekday_chart.png') }}" alt="{{ search_value }}의 요일별 승차총승객수">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
                                DataTable Example
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table id="datatablesSimple" class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>사용일자</th>
                                            <th>노선명</th>
                                            <th>역명</th>
                                            <th>승차총승객수</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>사용일자</th>
                                            <th>노선명</th>
                                            <th>역명</th>
                                            <th>승차총승객수</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {% for row in rows %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ row.사용일자 }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ row.노선명 }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ row.역명 }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ row.승차총승객수 }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
                <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                            <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2023</div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                &middot;
                                <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="static/js/scripts_login.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="static/assets/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="static/assets/demo/chart-bar-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/umd/simple-datatables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="static/js/datatables-simple-demo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code below is to retrieve and analyze the data of the external csv file.
csv file name is 'SUBWAY*MONTH.csv' and code name is 'read*_csv.py'

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import sqlite3

def read_csv_and_insert_to_db():
    filename = "flask/SUBWAY_MONTH.csv"
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')

    # SQLite 데이터베이스 연결
    conn = sqlite3.connect('flask/subway_data.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # 데이터를 subway_data 테이블로 저장
    data.to_sql('subway_data', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'AppleGothic'
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False

filename = "flask/SUBWAY_MONTH.csv"

# CSV 파일을 DataFrame으로 읽어오기
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')

# '시청' 역의 일별 승차총승객수 그래프 그리기 함수
def draw_si_station_chart():
    # '시청' 역의 데이터만 추출
    si_data = data[data['역명'] == '시청'].copy()  # .copy() 추가
    # 날짜(datetime) 형식으로 변환
    si_data['사용일자'] = pd.to_datetime(si_data['사용일자'], format='%Y%m%d')
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
    plt.plot(si_data['사용일자'], si_data['승차총승객수'], marker='o')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('flask/static/si_station_chart.png')


# '시청' 역의 요일별 승차총승객수 바 차트 그리기 함수
def draw_si_station_weekday_chart():
    # '시청' 역의 데이터만 추출
    시청_data = data[data['역명'] == '시청'].copy()  # 복사본 생성
    # 사용일자를 datetime 형식으로 변환
    시청_data.loc[:, '사용일자'] = pd.to_datetime(시청_data['사용일자'], format='%Y%m%d')
    # 사용일자에서 요일을 추출 (0: 월요일, 1: 화요일, ..., 6: 일요일)
    시청_data.loc[:, '요일'] = 시청_data['사용일자'].dt.dayofweek
    # 요일 이름으로 변환
    요일별_이름 = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일']
    시청_data.loc[:, '요일명'] = 시청_data['요일'].apply(lambda x: 요일별_이름[x])
    # 요일 순서를 월요일부터 일요일까지로 변경
    요일별_이름_변경 = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일']
    # 요일별 승차총승객수 합계 계산 및 요일 순서대로 정렬
    요일별_승차총승객수 = 시청_data.groupby('요일명')['승차총승객수'].sum().loc[요일별_이름_변경]

    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
    요일별_승차총승객수.plot(kind='bar', color='skyblue')
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('flask/static/si_station_weekday_chart.png')

# '종각'역의 일별승차총승객수 그래프 그리기 함수
def draw_jong_station_chart():
    # '종각' 역의 데이터만 추출
    jong_data = data[data['역명'] == '종각'].copy()
    # 날짜(datetime) 형식으로 변환
    jong_data['사용일자'] = pd.to_datetime(jong_data['사용일자'], format='%Y%m%d')
    # 날짜별 승차총승객수에 대한 꺾은선 그래프 그리기
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
    plt.plot(jong_data['사용일자'], jong_data['승차총승객수'], marker='o')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('flask/static/jong_station_chart.png')

# '종각' 역의 요일별 승차총승객수 바 차트 그리기 함수
def draw_jong_station_weekday_chart():
    # '종각' 역의 데이터만 추출
    종각_data = data[data['역명'] == '종각'].copy()
    # 사용일자를 datetime 형식으로 변환
    종각_data.loc[:, '사용일자'] = pd.to_datetime(종각_data['사용일자'], format='%Y%m%d')
    # 사용일자에서 요일을 추출 (0: 월요일, 1: 화요일, ..., 6: 일요일)
    종각_data.loc[:, '요일'] = 종각_data['사용일자'].dt.dayofweek
    # 요일 이름으로 변환
    요일별_이름 = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일']
    종각_data.loc[:, '요일명'] = 종각_data['요일'].apply(lambda x: 요일별_이름[x])
    # 요일 순서를 월요일부터 일요일까지로 변경
    요일별_이름_변경 = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일']
    # 요일별 승차총승객수 합계 계산 및 요일 순서대로 정렬
    요일별_승차총승객수 = 종각_data.groupby('요일명')['승차총승객수'].sum().loc[요일별_이름_변경]

    # 요일별 막대 그래프 그리기
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    요일별_승차총승객수.plot(kind='bar', color='skyblue')
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('flask/static/jong_station_weekday_chart.png')

# '서울'역의 일별승차총승객수 그래프 그리기 함수
def draw_se_station_chart():
    # '서울' 역의 데이터만 추출
    se_data = data[data['역명'] == '서울역'].copy()
    # 날짜(datetime) 형식으로 변환
    se_data['사용일자'] = pd.to_datetime(se_data['사용일자'], format='%Y%m%d')

    # 날짜별 승차총승객수에 대한 꺾은선 그래프 그리기
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
    plt.plot(se_data['사용일자'], se_data['승차총승객수'], marker='o')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('flask/static/se_station_chart.png')

def draw_se_station_weekday_chart():
    # '서울' 역의 데이터만 추출
    서울_data = data[data['역명'] == '서울역'].copy()
    # 사용일자를 datetime 형식으로 변환
    서울_data.loc[:, '사용일자'] = pd.to_datetime(서울_data['사용일자'], format='%Y%m%d')
    # 사용일자에서 요일을 추출 (0: 월요일, 1: 화요일, ..., 6: 일요일)
    서울_data.loc[:, '요일'] = 서울_data['사용일자'].dt.dayofweek
    # 요일 이름으로 변환
    요일별_이름 = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일']
    서울_data.loc[:, '요일명'] = 서울_data['요일'].apply(lambda x: 요일별_이름[x])
    # 요일 순서를 월요일부터 일요일까지로 변경
    요일별_이름_변경 = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일']
    # 요일별 승차총승객수 합계 계산 및 요일 순서대로 정렬
    요일별_승차총승객수 = 서울_data.groupby('요일명')['승차총승객수'].sum().loc[요일별_이름_변경]

    # 요일별 막대 그래프 그리기
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
    요일별_승차총승객수.plot(kind='bar', color='skyblue')
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('flask/static/se_station_weekday_chart.png')
```

The code below is the code that performs the login function and search function with flask.
code file name is 'testing_Web.py'

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session, jsonify
import csv
import pandas as pd
from read_csv import draw_si_station_chart, draw_si_station_weekday_chart, draw_jong_station_chart, draw_jong_station_weekday_chart, draw_se_station_chart, draw_se_station_weekday_chart, read_csv_and_insert_to_db
import sqlite3


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'supersecretkey'

users = {
    'bean': '1234'
}

# Load data from CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('flask/SUBWAY_MONTH.csv', encoding='utf-8')  # 변경: 파일 경로 수정

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if username in users and users[username] == password:
            session['username'] = username
            return redirect('/index2')
        else:
            return render_template('404.html', error='Invalid username or password')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/index2")
def index2():
    return render_template('index2.html')

@app.route("/data")
def data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('flask/subway_data.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # 데이터베이스에서 데이터 가져오기
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM subway_data")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
    conn.close()

    return render_template('data.html', rows=rows)


@app.route('/si_station_daily_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def si_station_daily_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_value = request.form['searchInput']

        if search_value == '종각':
            # TODO: 해당 역의 그래프 이미지를 반환하는 코드 추가
            graph_image = 'jong_station_chart.png'
            return render_template('graph.html', graph_image=graph_image, search_value=search_value)
        elif search_value == '시청':
            # TODO: 해당 역의 그래프 이미지를 반환하는 코드 추가
            graph_image = 'si_station_chart.png'
            return render_template('graph.html', graph_image=graph_image, search_value=search_value)
        else:
            # 다른 경우를 처리하거나 에러 메시지를 반환합니다
            return render_template('data.html', search_value=search_value)

    return render_template('data.html')


@app.route("/jong_station_daily_data")
def jong_station_daily_data():
    # 사용자의 검색어를 가져옵니다
    search_value = request.args.get('search_value', '')

    if search_value == '종각':
        # TODO: 해당 역의 그래프 이미지를 반환하는 코드 추가
        graph_image = 'jong_station_chart.png'
        return render_template('graph.html', graph_image=graph_image)
    else:
        # 다른 경우를 처리하거나 에러 메시지를 반환합니다
        return render_template('data.html')

@app.route("/se_station_daily_data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def se_station_daily_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_value = request.form['searchInput']

        if search_value == '서울':
            # TODO: 해당 역의 그래프 이미지를 반환하는 코드 추가
            graph_image = 'se_station_chart.png'
            return render_template('graph.html', graph_image=graph_image, search_value=search_value)
        else:
            # 다른 경우를 처리하거나 에러 메시지를 반환합니다
            return render_template('data.html', search_value=search_value)
    
    return render_template('data.html')
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    draw_si_station_chart()
    draw_si_station_weekday_chart()
    draw_jong_station_chart()
    draw_jong_station_weekday_chart()
    draw_se_station_chart()
    draw_se_station_weekday_chart()
    read_csv_and_insert_to_db()  # CSV 데이터를 데이터베이스로 이전

    app.run()
```

First, if you search in the search box below, png appears in the 'fas fa-chart-area me-1' part and 'fas fa-chart-bar me-1'part according to the search term.
When you run testing_Web.py, the following error character appears. 'jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'search_value'

Second, you see the data in the data table. I'm planning to use SQLite to save data in DB and load it

Comment: It seems as though you're not sending the value for `search_value` when returning the page. Given that it is not defined (`undefined`), functions such as `filename=search_value.lower()` will fail, breaking the whole page. Additionally, you'll need to consider what happens to this HTML element if "_no useful value_" is given and the image URL doesn't match anything on the server